# Как правильно переписать wpdb::escape

Tags: php, wordpress

> Notice: Функция wpdb::escape с версии
> 3.6 считается устаревшей! Используйте wpdb::prepare() or esc_sql().

```
if ( $user->exists() ) {
    if ( empty( $user->display_name ) )
        $user->display_name=$user->user_login;
    $comment_author       = $wpdb->escape($user->display_name);
    $comment_author_email = $wpdb->escape($user->user_email);
    $comment_author_url   = $wpdb->escape($user->user_url);
    $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
    if ( current_user_can('unfiltered_html') ) {
        if ( wp_create_nonce('unfiltered-html-comment_' . $comment_post_ID) != $_POST['_wp_unfiltered_html_comment'] ) {
            kses_remove_filters(); // start with a clean slate
            kses_init_filters(); // set up the filters
        }
    }
} else {
    if ( get_option('comment_registration') || 'private' == $status )
        wp_die( 'Вы должны зарегистрироваться или войти, чтобы оставлять комментарии.' );
}
```

просто $wpdb->prepare вместо $wpdb->escape не выходит

> Notice: Функция wpdb::prepare вызвана
> неправильно. Аргумент запроса метода
> wpdb::prepare() должен содержать
> описатель преобразований.

Comment: @rodion, я так понимаю, что `$wpdb->prepare();` необходим для [параметризованных запросов](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Вы же пытаетесь применить её к данным, которые уже получили. Полученные данные желательно санитизировать. Для WP [нашёл вот это](http://goo.gl/OiMXdt). Так или иначе, Вам никто не мешает воспользоваться [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strip-tags.php) и [htmlspecialchars](http://goo.gl/B3VPFL) для строковых данных, либо [нативными фильтрами](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-var.php).